# Html-Javascript-Php .pls Streamer

Tags: php, javascript, html

A simple question, does anyone know of a ".pls" streamer or something close to it were I can make a Internet Radio Streamer?
Using any of:
-Html
-JS
-Css
-Php

Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/).

It's a jquery plugin that uses HTML5 to handle audio/video. It also can default to flash if HTML5 is not available in the users browser.

There 's a somewhat strong community following which is good if your a begginer in this sort of thing. Here's a full tutorial and guide [Tuts](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-fundamentals)

Here is a quick demo for audio: [DEMO](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/)

If this isn't quite what your looking for let me know...

**EDIT:**

If you want to try a few software solutions that would allow you to do what you are asking there are a bunch out there.

Here are a few:

- [ShoutCast](http://www.shoutcast.com)
- [RadioDJ](http://www.radiodj.ro/)
- [iradeo](http://www.iradeo.com/)

Comment: is it possible to make a internet radio streamer out of it?

Comment: Jplayer supports any of these file formats. http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-essential-formats With that being said, you could definitely make a radio streamer with it. Not sure if that is the easiest way in terms of scaling or UI but, without knowing the intricate details of what you plan to do Id say this is a good starting point.